# Java String empty although printed out and not empty before

Tags: java, string

I want to read some HTTP Requestst and have this:

```
public class HTTPServerThread extends Thread {
private Socket socket = null;
private BufferedOutputStream out;

public HTTPServerThread(Socket socket) {
    super("HTTPServerThread");
    this.socket = socket;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream())));

        String request = "";
        String temp;
        while ((temp = in.readLine()) != null) {
            request += temp+"\n";
            System.out.println("request:\n"+request);
        }
        System.out.println("request final:\n"+request);
        if (request.equals("")) System.out.println("Request empty");

        out.close();
        socket.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

When I run my code and request something at my Server the request gets printed out part by part in the while loop, so everything works. But when I finally print it out, it gives me "" and so prints out "Request empty" and I don't know what my (probably stupid) mistake is, so please help me :)

current output:

```
request:
GET / HTTP/1.1

request:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost

request:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive

request:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

request:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.0 Safari/537.36

request:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.0 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch

request:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.0 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6

request:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.0 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6


request final:

Request empty
```

class with main:

```
public class HTTPServer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    int port;
    boolean listening = true;

    //read port from args[0] if exists, else port = 80

    if (args.length == 0) {
        port = 80;
    }
    else {
        port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    }

    //start listening on port

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not listen on port: "+port);
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    System.out.println("Java HTTP-Server");
    System.out.println("Port: " + port);

    //start new Thread if someone wants to connect

    while (listening)
        new HTTPServerThread(serverSocket.accept()).start();

    serverSocket.close();
}
```

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder` to concat just FYI !

Comment: Could you post the current output?

Comment: You're saying that the println in the loop shows a non-empty value for "request", but the following println doesn't?  If so, there's something you're not showing us.

Comment: Took your code, used a file instead to get data and it works perfectly. Is this called from multiple threads?

Comment: Does it matter that it is a thread and this piece of block is in the `run()` method?

Comment: If another thread would be launching the same method before the final request is printed, `request` might be initialized back to `""` before the call to the last print.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau: request seems to be a local variable, and not a field that is shared between threads.

Comment: @philipp94831: my guess is that the actual code is more complex than that. Please show us the actual code.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau yeah, I think there are two requests but I thougth my Server class would start another Thread for this and so why should the request of one thread should be overwritten by another?

Comment: As JBNizet said, without showing us more code and knowing how it is called, we're just wild guessing.

Comment: `Does it matter that it is a thread?` lol of course not, un-explainable behavior never has anything to do with threads! Follow up disclosure: `Does it matter that in fact "request" is actually a global variable?`...

Comment: Hope new version helps you more...

Comment: You probably have two of your threads running in parallel. The first one prints the 7 first line it receives, and is then blocked in its loop because the server doesn't send anything more, and the second one receives an empty response from the server, and prints its empty response. Add the current thread to your log statements to confirm or infirm.

Comment: If this is happening in a multithreaded environment there might be an issue here that some other thread has already called `out.close(); socket.close();` while other thread doesn't get to read anything from BufferedReader instance.

Comment: @anubhava but every thread should use another socket I think (this is my comprehension of `accept()` from the oracle docu)

Comment: There is something wrong with `temp` on the last iteration of your loop, notice your `request` output gets duplicated but with an extra empty line.

Comment: @philipp94831: Fair point, can you add current thread id to your logs and retest?

Comment: @anubhava okay, the request finals threa id is 10, before its 9

Comment: If that is the case, modifying your stop condition to `while ((temp = in.readLine()) != null && temp.length() > 0)` should unlock the thread that got stuck.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, you have the solution, thank you very much (and to the others: thank you, too :))

Comment: @philipp94831 I'll post an answer just so you can mark this question as answered and resolved.

Comment: Keep in mind that, if you *are* running multiple threads, the outputs will be interleaved in an unpredictable fashion.

Comment: @HotLicks yeah, but output was just for debugging so everything is good for me now

Comment: The problem is that it's hard to tell whether the sequence of output you're seeing is the result of a single thread or several interleaved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368640/java-string-empty-although-printed-out-and-not-empty-before?noredirect=1#comment25209425_17368640) guessed, the problem is being caused by the original thread getting stuck in the `while` loop, while a second thread actually prints the empty string.

The last iteration of the `while` loop results in an empty, but not null, `temp` string, as can be seen from the seemingly duplicated request output with an extra empty line right before the thread gets stuck.

So changing the stop condition to

```
while ((temp = in.readLine()) != null && temp.length() > 0) {
```

will allow the original thread to exit the loop and print the correct final request.

Answer (score -3):

you should put a ip and port to your socket

your socket don't know to go where

use this:

`Socket socket=new Socket(int ip , int port);`

Comment: -1 post and +1 @Arthur I think OP already receives data from his socket so we can assume it is correctly set

Comment: What has this got to do with the question? Add such things as comments, if you wish.

Comment: I have no porblem receiving anything, it also worked with only reading the first line directly into request and printing it out...